# Show that either $K(X)$ is a finite extension of $L$ or that $L=K$

Tags: galois-theory

$K$ is a field and $Y = p(X) / q(X) \in K(X) $ is a non-constant, rational function. I am asked to find a polynomial in variable $t$ and coefficients in $K(Y)$ such that $X$ would be a root.

I am then asked to show that if $L$ is a subfield of $K(X)$ containing $K$ then either $K(X)$ is a finite extension of $L$ or $L=K$

For the first part, if I can show that $q(X)$ is in the field $K(X)$, then I think the desired function would be easy to find, but I can't show this and I'm starting to think perhaps this is not the best approach.

For the second part, I am trying to show that $L\neq K \Rightarrow |K(X) : L| < \infty$ but I'm unsure of how I can go about this. I know that $|L:K| \neq 1$ but I am not sure how this helps me.

Any advice for either part would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is $Y$ and how does it relate to $X$? Do you mean to say $K(X)$? In this case you can just use the polynomial $t-X$. For the second part, just notice that any $L$ such that $K\subsetneq L \subset K(X)$ contains some polynomial $f(X)$ of degree $n$. Then you can show that $X$ can be obtained by at most a degree $n$ extension of $L$.

Comment: @Ravi

I think that $Y$ is a function of $X$ in the field of functions $K(X)$ such that is is a non-constant rational function. i.e. that there exist polynomials $p(X), q(X) \in K(X)$ such that $Y = \frac{p(X)}{q(x)}$.

We are then asked to find a polynomial $f(t)$ in the ring $(K(Y))[t]$ such that $f(X) = 0$.

I think an example of a function in $(K(Y))[t]$ would be:

$$g(t) = p_0(Y)t^0 + \dots +p_n(

Y)t^n $$ where $p_i(Y)$ are functions in the field of functions $K(Y)$

I don't think I can just take $f(t) = t-X$ since we don't know that $X \in K(Y)$

Comment: @Ravi 

Also I am unsure how I can show that if such an $L$ contained a polynomial $f(X)$ of degree $n$ that $X$ may be recovered by at most $n$ extensions of $L$

Comment: You should specify that in your question. In that case, why not try $Yq(t)-p(t)$? Then $X$ does satisfy this equation which lives in $K[Y](t)$.

Comment: @Ravi

Ah you're right, that was what I wanted to construct but I was confused on what I actually needed to show that it exists in $K(Y)\left[t\right]$, sorry my mistake.

I am still unsure how to show that $X$ can be recovered from an $n$ degree polynomial in at most $n$ extensions.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're missing. We have everything: You have the field $K(Y)$ and you know that $X$, which generates $K(X)$ over $K$ satisfies the polynomial $Yq(t)-p(t) $ equation over $K(Y)$ and so $[K(X):K(Y)]$ is a finite extension of $K(Y)$ of degree at most the degree of $Yq(t)-p(t) $.